# Can you use React-fiber/Three.js in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-fiber

How is it going StackOverflow community so I was wondering could I use React-fiber in React-Native

Answer (score 0):

in theory yes, or at least you could/can if you use v5. in newer r3f versions there is no RN support. this PR (https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/pull/1384) will fix that, but it needs completion, someone that knows RN will have to review and add events.